# DirectSound captures gigabytes of frames instead of megabytes

Tags: c++, audio, capture, directsound

I am using DirectSound to capture the sound of my desktop, using the tutorial from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416968(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem is that when I start to capture, my WAV file gets to hundreds of MB and even GB, in a few seconds.When I play the WAV file, 5 seconds of audio capture become 30 minutes, and the same frame of sound is duplicated like 1000 times.I have noticed that WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 and 2 are never fired.Thanks in advance.

```
bool captureSound = false;
wav_header wavFile; // the wav file
UINT totalData = 0;
LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTURE8 capturer = NULL;
GUID guid = DSDEVID_DefaultCapture;
HRESULT err;
DSCBUFFERDESC dscbd;
LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTUREBUFFER8 pDSCB8;
DWORD g_dwNextCaptureOffset = 0;
DWORD g_dwCaptureBufferSize = 0;
DWORD g_dwNotifySize = 0;

#define cEvents  3

WAVEFORMATEX         wfx;  
HANDLE     rghEvent[cEvents] = {0,0,0};
DSBPOSITIONNOTIFY  rgdsbpn[cEvents];

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;
    BOOL  bDone; 

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT2));


    bDone = FALSE;
    // Main message loop:
    while( !bDone ) {
         dwResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( 3, rghEvent,    
                                             FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS ); 
         switch( dwResult ) {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: 
                if(FAILED(RecordCapturedData())) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
                break;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: 
                if(FAILED(RecordCapturedData())) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
                break;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2: 
                if(FAILED(RecordCapturedData())) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
                break;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 3:
                //MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("wait3"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
                // Windows messages are available
                while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                    {
                        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
                        {
                            TranslateMessage(&msg);
                            DispatchMessage(&msg);
                        }
                        if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )   
                            bDone = TRUE; 
                    }
                break;
         }
    }

    //CloseHandle(rghEvent);

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_CAPTURESOUND:
            captureSound = true;
            if (FAILED(createWav(&wavFile)))
            {
                closeWav(wavFile.pFile);
                MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error creating the sound file!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
            }

            // add the WAV header
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                fputc(wavFile.riff_header[i], wavFile.pFile);
            }
            fwrite((char*)&wavFile.wav_size,sizeof(int),1,wavFile.pFile);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                fputc(wavFile.wave_header[i], wavFile.pFile);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                fputc(wavFile.fmt_header[i], wavFile.pFile);
            }
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.fmt_chunk_size,4,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.audio_format,2,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.num_channels,2,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.sample_rate,4,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.byte_rate,4,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.sample_alignment,2,1,wavFile.pFile);
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.bit_depth,2,1,wavFile.pFile);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                fputc(wavFile.data_header[i], wavFile.pFile);
            }
            fwrite((const char*)&wavFile.data_bytes,4,1,wavFile.pFile);

            /* Use DirectSoundCaptureCreate8() to create and initialize an object and get the pointer (pDSC8) to IDirectSoundCapture8 */
            if(FAILED(DirectSoundCaptureCreate8(&guid, &capturer, NULL))) {
                ErrorExit(TEXT("DirectSoundCaptureCreate8"));
            }

            /* Use the method CreateCaptureBuffer() of IDirectSoundCapture8(pDSC8->CreateSoundBuffer()) to create 
            and initialize an object and get the  pointer (pDSCB) to IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer. */
            if(FAILED(CreateCaptureBuffer(capturer,&pDSCB8))) {
                 ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateCaptureBuffer"));    
            }

            /* Use the method QueryInterface of  IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer8(pDSCB8->QueryInterface()) to get a pointer(lpDsNotify) to the interface IDirectSoundNotify8. */
            if(FAILED(SetCaptureNotifications(pDSCB8))) {
                 ErrorExit(TEXT("SetCaptureNotifications"));    
            }

            /* Start capturing */
            if(FAILED(pDSCB8->Start( DSCBSTART_LOOPING ) ) )
                ErrorExit(TEXT("Start"));   
            else MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Started capturing!"), TEXT("Good"), MB_OK);
            break;
        case IDM_OPRESTE:
            captureSound = false;

            // Stop the buffer, and read any data that was not    
            // caught by a notification 

            if( FAILED(pDSCB8->Stop() ) )   
                 ErrorExit(TEXT("Stop"));

            if(FAILED(RecordCapturedData())) MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("ERROR "), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);


            /* Update the fields in the WAV header and close the file */
            fseek (wavFile.pFile, 4 , SEEK_SET );
            wavFile.wav_size += totalData;
            fwrite((char*)&wavFile.wav_size,sizeof(int),1,wavFile.pFile);

            wavFile.data_bytes += totalData;
            fseek (wavFile.pFile, 40 , SEEK_SET );
            fwrite((char*)&wavFile.data_bytes,sizeof(int),1,wavFile.pFile);

            closeWav(wavFile.pFile);  
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd); // POSTS THE MESSAGE WM_DESTROY TO DESTROY THE CREATED WINDOW.
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE: 
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

HRESULT CreateCaptureBuffer(LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTURE8 pDSC, 
                            LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTUREBUFFER8* ppDSCB8)
{
  HRESULT hr;
  DSCBUFFERDESC               dscbd;
  LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTUREBUFFER  pDSCB;

  // Set up WAVEFORMATEX for 44.1 kHz 16-bit stereo. 
  WAVEFORMATEX                wfx =
  {WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, wavFile.num_channels, wavFile.sample_rate, wavFile.byte_rate, wavFile.sample_alignment, wavFile.bit_depth, 0};
    // wFormatTag, nChannels, nSamplesPerSec, mAvgBytesPerSec,
    // nBlockAlign, wBitsPerSample, cbSize

  if ((NULL == pDSC) || (NULL == ppDSCB8)) return E_INVALIDARG;
  dscbd.dwSize = sizeof(DSCBUFFERDESC);
  dscbd.dwFlags = 0;
  dscbd.dwBufferBytes = wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec;
  dscbd.dwReserved = 0;
  dscbd.lpwfxFormat = &wfx;
  dscbd.dwFXCount = 0;
  dscbd.lpDSCFXDesc = NULL;

  g_dwNotifySize = MAX( 1024, wavFile.byte_rate / 8 );
  g_dwNotifySize -= g_dwNotifySize % wavFile.sample_alignment;
  g_dwCaptureBufferSize = g_dwNotifySize * 3;

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pDSC->CreateCaptureBuffer(&dscbd, &pDSCB, NULL)))
  {
    /* Use the method QueryInterface of  IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer(pDSCB->QueryInterface()) to get a 
    pointer(pDSCB8) to the interface IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer8 */
    hr = pDSCB->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectSoundCaptureBuffer8, (LPVOID*)ppDSCB8);
    pDSCB->Release();  


  }
  return hr;
}

HRESULT SetCaptureNotifications(LPDIRECTSOUNDCAPTUREBUFFER8 pDSCB)
{
  LPDIRECTSOUNDNOTIFY8 pDSNotify;
  HRESULT    hr;

  if (NULL == pDSCB) return E_INVALIDARG;
  if (FAILED(hr = pDSCB->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectSoundNotify, (LPVOID*)&pDSNotify)))
  {
    return hr;
  }
  if (FAILED(hr = pDSCB->GetFormat(&wfx, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX), NULL)))
  {
    return hr;
  }

  // Create events.
  for (int i = 0; i < cEvents; ++i)
  {
    rghEvent[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == rghEvent[i])
    {
      hr = GetLastError();
      return hr;
    }
  }

  // Describe notifications. 

  rgdsbpn[0].dwOffset = (wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec/2) -1;
  rgdsbpn[0].hEventNotify = rghEvent[0];

  rgdsbpn[1].dwOffset = wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec - 1;
  rgdsbpn[1].hEventNotify = rghEvent[1];

  rgdsbpn[2].dwOffset = DSBPN_OFFSETSTOP;
  rgdsbpn[2].hEventNotify = rghEvent[2];

  /* Use the SetNotificationPositions() of IDirectSoundNotify8(lpDsNotify->SetNotificationPositions())
  to set the notification buffer positions */

  hr = pDSNotify->SetNotificationPositions(cEvents, rgdsbpn);
  pDSNotify->Release();
  return hr;
}

HRESULT RecordCapturedData() 
    {
      HRESULT hr;
      VOID* pbCaptureData  = NULL;
      DWORD dwCaptureLength;
      VOID* pbCaptureData2 = NULL;
      DWORD dwCaptureLength2;
      VOID* pbPlayData   = NULL;
      UINT  dwDataWrote;
      DWORD dwReadPos;
      LONG lLockSize;

      if (NULL == pDSCB8)
          MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Empty buffer!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
      if (NULL == wavFile.pFile)
          MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Empty .wav file!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

      if (FAILED (hr = pDSCB8->GetCurrentPosition( 
        NULL, &dwReadPos)))
          MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Failed to get current position!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

      // Lock everything between the private cursor 
      // and the read cursor, allowing for wraparound.

      lLockSize = dwReadPos - g_dwNextCaptureOffset;
      if( lLockSize < 0 ) lLockSize += g_dwCaptureBufferSize;

      // Block align lock size so that we are always write on a boundary   
      //lLockSize -= (lLockSize % g_dwNotifySize);   

      if( lLockSize == 0 ) return S_FALSE;

      if (FAILED(hr = pDSCB8->Lock( 
            g_dwNextCaptureOffset, lLockSize, 
            &pbCaptureData, &dwCaptureLength, 
            &pbCaptureData2, &dwCaptureLength2, 0L)))
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Lock failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

      // Write the data. This is done in two steps
      // to account for wraparound.

      if (FAILED( addData(&wavFile, (BYTE*)pbCaptureData, dwCaptureLength, &dwDataWrote)))
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error writting to the file!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

      if (pbCaptureData2 != NULL)
      {
        if (FAILED( addData(&wavFile, (BYTE*)pbCaptureData2, dwCaptureLength2, &dwDataWrote)))
          MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Error writting to the file 2!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
      }

      // Unlock the capture buffer.

     pDSCB8->Unlock( pbCaptureData, dwCaptureLength, 
        pbCaptureData2, dwCaptureLength2  );

      // Move the capture offset forward.

      g_dwNextCaptureOffset += dwCaptureLength; 
      g_dwNextCaptureOffset %= g_dwCaptureBufferSize; 
      g_dwNextCaptureOffset += dwCaptureLength2; 
      g_dwNextCaptureOffset %= g_dwCaptureBufferSize; 

      totalData += (dwCaptureLength + dwCaptureLength2);
      return S_OK;
    }
```

Wav writer utility

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wav.h"

HRESULT createWav(wav_header* pWav) {
    pWav->pFile = fopen("sound.wav","w");
    if(pWav->pFile == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(pWav->riff_header, "RIFF");
    strcpy(pWav->wave_header, "WAVE");
    strcpy(pWav->fmt_header, "fmt ");
    pWav->fmt_chunk_size = 16;
    pWav->audio_format = 1;
    pWav->num_channels = 2;
    pWav->sample_rate = 44100; // 44.1 KHz - CD-quality audio
    pWav->bit_depth = 16; // Bits per Sample – The number of bits available for one sample. 
    pWav->sample_alignment = pWav->num_channels * (pWav->bit_depth)/8; // This is the number of bytes in a frame
    pWav->byte_rate = pWav->sample_rate * pWav->sample_alignment; // number of bytes per second captured
    strcpy(pWav->data_header, "data");
    pWav->data_bytes = 0; // n * frames , n = 0 empty data default, to be updated each time new data is added
    pWav->wav_size = 36 + pWav->data_bytes; // to be updated each time new data is added

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT closeWav(FILE * pFile) {
    fclose(pFile);
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT addData(wav_header* pWav, VOID* data,UINT dataLength, UINT* dataWrote) {
    // set the positon back at the end of the file
    fseek (pWav->pFile, 0 , SEEK_END );
    *dataWrote = fwrite((const char*)data,sizeof(byte),(size_t)dataLength, pWav->pFile);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition for the `addData` function?

Comment: sure,check above

Comment: Your notification offsets have no direct relation to the size of your capture buffer.  Your recorder (writer) manages the start location of the write on its own, is will be getting it wrong.  Possibly the computation of `lLockSize` results in a much larger size than it should be using, resulting in the large writes to the .wav file.

Comment: Your header isn't quite right. The file size follows immediately after the *riff* section (actually this field should be set to *fileSize-8* because the riff section is 8 bytes long). Also, you shouldn't rely on SEEK_END, rather check that *dataWrote is the same as dataLength, otherwise your code isn't going to work.

Comment: I do put the file size correctly, here is what I do after I stop recording  fseek (wavFile.pFile, 4 , SEEK_SET );
wavFile.wav_size += totalData;
fwrite((char*)&wavFile.wav_size,sizeof(int),1,wavFile.pFile);

wavFile.data_bytes += totalData;
fseek (wavFile.pFile, 40 , SEEK_SET );
         fwrite((char*)&wavFile.data_bytes,sizeof(int),1,wavFile.pFile);

closeWav(wavFile.pFile);

Comment: fixed, it had to do with the iLockSize . just removed g_dwNotifySize = MAX( 1024, wavFile.byte_rate / 8 );
  g_dwNotifySize -= g_dwNotifySize % wavFile.sample_alignment;
  g_dwCaptureBufferSize = g_dwNotifySize * 3;